# create metabox to activate slider

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, metabox

I want to create a checkbox on the Add Post page to enable the slider
When the checkbox is activated, that post displayed in the slider,
and i want to just write code i don't want to use any plugin.

Comment: Would you consider writing code as a plugin? Plugin reccomendations are off topic on this stack anyway

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with the checkbox and metabox, that's limiting:

- You're only able to have a single slider, and have to add code for every new slider to add a new checkbox
- Data gets stored in post meta as a custom field, but querying posts by their post meta is super expensive and slow

So I present, an alternative that's much, much easier to implement, and far more flexible:

### Use a non-hierarchical Slider Taxonomy

This gives you:

- free archives should you want to expand on your sliders ( optional ofcourse )
- **A free UI**
- Querying posts for the slider is now super **super fast**. This is faster than a checkbox in a metabox by orders of magnitude
- The queries scale up as traffic increases and post counts increase. Post meta queries don't scale
- A free user interface in the form of a checkbox list ( so it's technically a metabox with a checkbox, funny how that turns out! )
- A slider management UI, under posts you'll get a page where you can see all your sliders, name them, add descriptions, see how many posts they have, delete/add
- Slider meta! Now you have `slider` terms, you can add term meta! A term meta for transition style? Transition speed? So many possibilities
- Posts can now appear in multiple sliders

For example this post appears in a slider named `homepage`, no prizes for where that slider might appear:

[image]

A post can even appear in multiple sliders!

### How Do I setup The Taxonomy?

You would call `register_taxonomy` on the `init` action, like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_morteza_slider_tax' );

function create_morteza_slider_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'morteza_slider',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Sliders' ),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'public' => false
        )
    );
}
```

### How Do I fetch the posts for my slider?

You use the taxonomy name as a parameter in the post query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'morteza_slider' => 'homepage' // <-- this is all that's needed
] );
```

Then follow it up with a standard post loop:

```
// a standard post loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo 'start slider markup';

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // TODO: output this post as a slide
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo 'end slider markup';
}
```

Making sure to swap out the various bits, e.g. the "start slider markup" gets replaced with whatever your slider library requires to work

Comment: i did,
how its work ?
Is there another way?
working with metabox is easier!

Comment: Reread the answer, I'm unsure which parts you didn't understand, perhaps you could clarify? Keep in mind that the code to set this up is literally the last code block with no changes, and there's an example of how to fetch the posts for a slider too. Try the code out

Comment: I've restructured the answer a little, hopefully that helps, metaboxes involve more work and are more slower and require more code